# Does it make sense to cache trigonometric functions in OpenGL ES?

Tags: opengl-es, glsl

I know trig function caches were very popular when doing graphics before GPU's but does it ever make sense to use a 1D texture lookup table to calculate sin/cos from a pre-computed value from within an OpenGL ES shader? Are there time savings if ultra high accuracy is not needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is one of those "it depends" questions.

High precision arbitrary `sin()` and `cos()` in particular tend to be expensive operations, as they are not often directly used in graphics and getting full precision tends to require some level of refinement iteration. So individually, it wouldn't surprise me if texturing could be faster.

A few caveats. Firstly, most uses of cosine for lighting is based on the angle between unit-length vectors so you don't need arbitrary `cos()` - just use `dot()` which GPUs are *very* efficient at.

Secondly, it's worth noting that some implementations (mobile GPUs in particular) will likely already be able to give you faster and less accurate results if you are computing at `mediump` precision. This will reduce whatever baseline cost for `sin()` or `cos()` in the logic below.

The rest of the question is really a whether the cost of `sin()` is better than the cost of a `texture()`, which is likely to depend very much on the rest of the shader program and the functional unit balance in the target GPU.

- If your shader is already dominated by texturing performance due to other unrelated texture operations, then adding more texturing will make it slower even if a single `texture()` call is individually faster than `sin()`.
- If your shader is dominated by arithmetic (or whatever unit(s) executes `sin()` calls) then performance may improve by moving some load off that to the texturing path.

Answer (score 1):

Yes it does make sense and you should cache it.

First, I read solidpixel's answer (it's mostly correct) but I'll diverge a bit from him.

So, in short: you should not calculate sin() nor cos() on run-time (specially in android - if that's your GLES case) because you don't know what GPU your shader will be running on and lots of them simply will never optimize it. There are better ways to cache it other than using texture sampling.

If you are dealing with linear algebra (most shader procedures are simple vector equation solvers), then:
you should use dot product to replace the need for `cos()` and cross product for `sin()`, like he said.

However if that's not your case and you really need to invoke sin and cos, then I recommend you cache it for sure, here are 2 best ways I like:

- `texture()` is indeed pretty expensive but you can use `textureGrad()` which is a pretty faster texture lookup than regular `texture()` because it skips all the filtering, although it's more limited, it's perfect for caching sin and cos.
- Another better solution is to not use texture at all: Use uniform buffers instead, it's going to be basically an array of floats (like the texture) but explicit to the GPU so you don't need to pass through sampling (which is specially expensive in mobile).
- uniform buffers have a size limitation so if you need better precision on the different values of your angle, you may use SSBOs (Shader buffer storage objects) which are like uniform buffers but can store much more data.

Comment: These are interesting insights, but it appears most everything you specified is OpenGL ES 3 which leaves out some of the devices that would need the speed increase the most.

Comment: Well, two things to keep in mind about that: ~79% of all androids run ES 3, and even those who don't run ES3 most likely will support (at least uniform buffers) as ARB extension. There could be a 5% that will not support anything at all, but for those, you may not even be able to do much on pixel shader anyways, so I'd recommend you calculate  `sin()` and `cos()` on CPU side and send as a matrix computed by vertices in the vertex shader instead (quality will be affected but that's the only way to run on very old and low end devices)